# Simple Client-Server program using Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I'm making a simple, **no thread** *Client*-*Server* program where GUI has one button on both *server* and *client* side. When *client* presses button it changes text on a button to **"C"** and sends to *server* **"C"** string, so the button on the *server* side changes text to **"C"**. *Server* works similarly to *client* but sends **"S"** instead of **"C"**. They work in turns: when it's the *client's* turn, *server's* button is locked and he cannot change his button. *Client* always starts first.

When *client* presses button it works fine, but when *server* presses button it changes button to **"S"** on the *server* side but not on *client's* side. I know what I'm doing wrong.

Server code:

```
public class Serv implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private boolean myTurn;
    private ServerSocket sock;
    private Socket s;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintStream output;

    public Serv() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        button = new JButton();
        myTurn = false;
        sock = new ServerSocket(9001);
        s = null;
        button = new JButton();
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe - Server");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        button = new JButton("");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        button.setFont(new Font(button.getFont().getName(), button.getFont().getStyle(), 70));
        button.setActionCommand("1");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startMyGame() throws IOException
    {
        createGUI();
        s = sock.accept();
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(true)
        {
            if(myTurn == false)
            {
                myTurn = true;
                String out = input.readLine();
                button.setText(out);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Serv tc = null;
        try
        {
            tc = new Serv();
            tc.startMyGame();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                tc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void close() throws IOException
    {
        this.sock.close();
        this.input.close();
        this.output.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(myTurn == true)
        {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
            {
                JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
                b.setText("S");
                output.println("S");
                myTurn = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Cli implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private boolean myTurn;
    private Socket sock;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private PrintStream output;

    public Cli() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        button = new JButton();
        myTurn = true;
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9001);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe - Client");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        button = new JButton("");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        button.setFont(new Font(button.getFont().getName(), button.getFont().getStyle(), 70));
        button.setActionCommand("1");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        mainPanel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startMyGame() throws IOException
    {
        createGUI();
        while(true)
        {
            if(myTurn == false)
            {
                myTurn = true;
                String out = input.readLine();
                button.setText(out);
            }
        }
    }

    private void close() throws IOException
    {
        this.sock.close();
        this.input.close();
        this.output.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Cli tc = null;
        try
        {
            tc = new Cli();
            tc.startMyGame();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                tc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(myTurn == true)
        {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
            {
                JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
                if(!b.getText().equals("X") || !b.getText().equals("O"))
                {
                    b.setText("C");
                    output.println("C");
                    myTurn = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have deleted imports so the codes would be shorter.

Comment: It looks like you never set the client socket to accept connections.

Comment: Your code is *not* so simple. As mentioned in comments to your deleted question your not-so-simple code is potentially blocking the Swing event thread with the always-running while loop. This type of code **needs** a background thread to run properly. Why have you not yet read the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) link as was advised to you previously?

Comment: @csmckelvey: please clarify. As far as I understand this, ServerSockets must accept connections, not client ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current issues with your code:

- You're creating a Swing GUI and running it *off* of the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT. GUI's should be started *on* the event thread so that all Swing code is guaranteed to run on a single thread.
- You've got a long-running while loop, and it is making Swing mutational calls, updating the state of a JButton. If this code were running on the Swing event thread, it would block/freeze the GUI. This block should be explicitly called in a background thread that is not the EDT, and all Swing calls should be queued onto the event thread as per the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial.
- You're using a non-volatile boolean in different threads, risking the variable not being changed when it should be changed
- You appear to be closing your streams immediately, preventing adequate communication between concerns.

Working on a cleaner example.......

For example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleServerClient {
    private static final int PORT = 9001;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                SimpleServer server = new SimpleServer(PORT, "Server", false);
                SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient(PORT, "Client", true);
                server.createGui();
                client.createGui();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
interface SimpleGui {
    void sendLine(String nextLine);
}
```

```
// background thread handles listening to the Scanner 
// which scans a Socket's InputStream
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    public static final String LINE = "line";
    private Scanner inputScanner;
    private SimpleGui gui;
    private String line = "";

    public MyWorker(Scanner inputScanner, SimpleGui gui) {
        this.inputScanner = inputScanner;
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (inputScanner.hasNext()) {
            // get line from Scanner                
            // use the setter method in case we want to use a PropertyChangeListener later
            setLine(inputScanner.nextLine());

            // send line to the GUI
            gui.sendLine(getLine());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return line;
    }

    // again rigged up to allow use of PropertyChangeListeners
    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
        firePropertyChange(LINE, null, line);
    }
}
```

```
// code that both the client and server GUI classes share
abstract class DefaultGui implements SimpleGui {

    // this guy ***must**** be volitile!
    private volatile boolean myTurn;
    protected Scanner inputScanner;
    protected PrintStream out;
    protected JButton button = new JButton("Blank");
    protected Socket socket;
    protected String name;
    protected int port;

    public DefaultGui(int port, String name, boolean myTurn) {
        this.port = port;
        this.name = name;
        this.myTurn = myTurn;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendLine(String nextLine) {
        button.setText(nextLine);
        myTurn = true;
    }

    public void createGui() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> actionPerformed(e));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        panel.add(button);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!myTurn) {
            return;
        }
        out.println(getName());
        button.setText(getName());
        myTurn = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```
class SimpleServer extends DefaultGui {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public SimpleServer(int port, String name, boolean myTurn) throws IOException {
        super(port, name, myTurn);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                // accept() blocks the current thread, so must be called on a background thread
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                inputScanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                new MyWorker(inputScanner, this).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
    }    
}
```

```
class SimpleClient extends DefaultGui {

    public SimpleClient(int port, String name, boolean myTurn) throws IOException {
        super(port, name, myTurn);
        socket = new Socket("localhost", port);
        inputScanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        new MyWorker(inputScanner, this).execute();
    }    
}
```